# Tish'a Vachamishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yitzchok was 159 years old when he was reunited with Ya'akov (upon his return from his stay with Lavan).

159 is the famous responsa of Rabbi Akiva Eiger where he deals with transactions that occur automatically on the Sabbath, with implications for e-commerce.

Comment: "Responsa" is plural; "responsum" for singular; no?

Answer (score 1):

Koton    =    159